# On iOS, Safari : How to prevent the underlay page/main page from scrolling but beyond the overlay. Overlay should be able to scroll

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, cross-browser

For only iOS : When you add overlay to the web HTML User Interface, you cannot prevent the underlay page from scrolling beyond the overlay by setting overflow: hidden on the body or html. This works perfectly fine on desktop and Android etc.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue be setting body's position to fixed and top, bottom, left, right to 0 when the overlay comes up. On closure reset the position to static.

```css
body {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  }
```